# Server-side validation in ASP.NET 2.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex, validation, server-side

My application is in ASP.NET 2.0 with C#. I have a regular expression validator with the regular expression `^[0-9]*(\\,)?[0-9]?[0-9]?$`, now my client don't want this validation at client side but on button click i.e. Server Side.

EX: I have to check the value of `txtPrice` textbox

Please let me know how can I put this regular expression validation on server side.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it is both client and server side and there should be a switch to to turn it off on the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CustomValidator which can link to a server side event:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_Validate"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Then server side you can validate input

```
protected void CustomValidator1_Validate (object source, ServerValidateEventArgs argss)
{}
```

Remember to wrap your submit button click with

```
if(IsValid) {}
```

To ensure all validators are respected

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `EnableClientScript="false"` to the validator.

Answer (score 1):

The control will validate on the server side always, regardless of whether you also enable client-side validation. But you must then remember to check the value of `Page.IsValid` before accepting the postback...

As has already been said, you can turn off client-side validation with an attribute.

Answer (score -1):

Client-side validation using server-side controls based on [ValidatorBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.aspx) takes place only on `PostBack` i.e. on any server-side button/linkbutton click.

So you can use [RegularExpressionValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx):

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPrice" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPrice" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]*(\\,)?[0-9]?[0-9]?$" ErrorMessage="Input is incorrect" />
```

Also you can use [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx):

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPrice" />
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPrice" ErrorMessage="Input is incorrect" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate" />

protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    // use e.Value to validate and set e.IsValid
    // it's different depending on control to validate.
    // for custom controls you can set it using ValidationPropertyAttribute
}
```

Comment: But I can't put <asp:regularexpressionValidator> on client side, I have to do same validation on server side .

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite: Do you mean - can't put in markup? Why not? (just interesting). Also you can use `CustomValidator` - see my updated post.

Comment: Looks like you edited your answer just to match what @webdude answered before you...

Comment: I am already using javascript function on the client click of that button and in this case my regularExpressionValidator is not working, for the same I have to put it on the server side.

Comment: @Darksider: No, I don't. Also his answer is scant and is a medley of C# and VB.NET syntax o__O